# Performance issue on web app Anjular js

Tags: angularjs

I am working on a application which deployed to several servers.  In two of the servers the performance is slow where on the one server performance is better than others.

They all are win 2012 server and IIS 8  and also share the same databases. 
It is a MVVM architecture where Angular js pages calls the webapi for all the database operation and other business logic.

Issue found to be on page load,  response from the database.

Can someone give a hint or idea what could be the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Are you using a minified version of angular? it will load faster than the unminified one.

Do you have a lot of js files? They could be concated together.

Do you have a lot of css files? they could also be concated together

Have your images been optimized? sometimes you can reduce jpegs by up to 50%.

All these things will help the page load faster.

Comment: Darin, yes over all the website is slow and the optionsthat you mention I would like to try and sure it will be helpful.  However, i am also looking for the soltuion that why the same web application is taking almost 40% extra in 2 of the servers while not on others.